# how to check async task is null or not

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch, webclient

I call an API with WebClient and async method, now I want to manage possible errors such as being null
I used try/catch but none of the exceptions work and can't catch the error

How can I catch the errors?

```
private async Task<string> GetTaskAsync(string API)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(API);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    catch (NullRefrenceException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if the task is null or if the task's result is null? The task should never be null.

Comment: @PauloMorgado i mean task result

Comment: It's no different than any other value.

Answer (score 4):

You should change the order of catches. NullReferenceException derives from Exception class so if a NullReferenceException occurs, it will be catched by the first catch block. You should do something like below.

```cs
try
{
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    return await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(API);
  }
}
catch (NullRefrenceException ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  return null;
}
```